# How to change appearance of org-mode files on Github?

Tags: github

Github supports org-mode files, and has a renderer that parses .org files and converts them to HTML form. Headings appear in larger font, text tables are converted to graphical HTML tables, etc.

Is there a way to control the way .org files appear on Github?

I tried adding some export options in the usual manner

```
#+OPTIONS:   H:2 toc:t
```

but the options are not reflected.

Is this possible? If not, is there a workaround to display org-mode files through Github?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a link to a GitHub project page that shows how GitHub renders org-mode files?

Answer (score 8):

The [github markup](https://github.com/github/markup) uses [org-ruby](https://github.com/bdewey/org-ruby) to convert org-mode to HTML. It is fairly basic and its README says:

> [...] Currently, you cannot do much to customize the conversion. The supplied textile conversion is optimized for extracting “content” from the orgfile as opposed to “metadata.”

That is not very specific, but it appears what you are trying to do is not possible. If you have a look at the source, you see it uses very few options like 'f', or 'num'. But 'toc', and 'H' are not being used.

I don't know of any workarounds, except to extend *org-ruby*.